# Save execute results into a table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Below is a simplified postgres stored procedure I am trying to run:

```
create or replace procedure my_schema.tst(suffix varchar) 
as $$
    
begin
    
    execute('   select *        
                into my_schema.MyTable_'||suffix||'
                From my_schema.MyTable
                '); 

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

When I attempt to run using something like:

```
call my_schema.tst('test');
```

I get this error **Invalid operation: EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not supported;**

Is it possible to execute a dynamic query that creates a new table? I have seen examples that look like:

```
Execute('... some query ...') into Table;
```

but for my use case I need the resulting tablename to be passed as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use `INSERT INTO tname SELECT...`

```
create or replace procedure my_schema.tst(suffix varchar) 
as $$
    
begin
    
    execute '  INSERT INTO my_schema.MyTable_'||suffix||' SELECT *        
                 FROM my_schema.MyTable
                '; 

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

or Use `CREATE TABLE tname AS SELECT...,` :

```
create or replace procedure my_schema.tst(suffix varchar) 
as $$
    
begin
    
    execute '  CREATE TABLE my_schema.MyTable_'||suffix||' as SELECT *        
                 FROM my_schema.MyTable
                '; 

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: The Create Table statement worked for my script. One follow up question... being new to postgres, should I be worried performance/memory-wise by using the 
(    execute '  CREATE TABLE my_schema.MyTable_'||suffix||' as SELECT *        
                 FROM my_schema.MyTable
                '; 
)
approach on large tables?

Comment: A `SELECT * FROM  table`  Always can be a performance bottleneck for large tables, it doesn't matter if is inside a `EXECUTE` or in a simple query

Comment: @Campo21: Why do you have to copy the data? It's already in your database and you can use it.